# Slideshow using MooTools JavaScript - How can I position slideshow to rescale in browser window

Tags: javascript, css, image, mootools, slideshow

I am trying to create a slideshow which fades images as the next one comes using Mootools Javascript. The slideshow works in the browser, but the layout is causing me a heartache. I have position it in a certain area of the webpage and whenever I re-size the browser window in both IE and Google Chrome, the slideshow does not re-scale. I don't know if the slideshow image is too large but it does not seem to fit into the window browser when making it smaller, it just extends to the left.

Here is the code in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TE75y/10/ (I am new to using JSFiddle, so please forgive the slight errors with the slideshow image).

The Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    /* settings */
    var showDuration = 3000;
    var container = $('banner-container');
    var images = container.getElements('img');
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var interval;
    /* opacity and fade */
    images.each(function(img,i){ 
        if(i > 0) {
            img.set('opacity',0);
        }
    });
    /* worker */
    var show = function() {
        images[currentIndex].fade('out');
        images[currentIndex = currentIndex < images.length - 1 ? currentIndex+1 : 0].fade('in');
    };
    /* start once the page is finished loading */
    window.addEvent('load',function(){
        interval = show.periodical(showDuration);
    });
});



 </script>
```

The HTML

```
<div id="banner-container">

<div>
<img src="../images/banner5.jpg" width="1090" height="340" alt="banner 5"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="../images/banner7.jpg" width="1090" height="340" alt="banner 7"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="../images/creamfields.jpg" width="1090" height="340" alt="creamfields"/>
</div>
<div>
<img src="../images/Creamfileds-Banner.jpg" width="1090" height="340" alt="creamfield 2"/>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#banner-container {
position: relative;
height: 340px;
width: 960px;
margin-left: 450px;
}
#banner-container > div {
position: absolute;
top: 55px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
}

#banner-container img {
display: block;
position: absolute;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
height: 340px;
width: 960px;
}
```

I would really appreciate some helpful solutions as I have tried most solutions which did not work and I just cannot seem to understand how to work round it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should reduce your sample code (including the jsFiddle) to the relevant parts only; it'll help users focus on the exact problem area. Additionally, since you copy/pasted the code directly, the images aren't working in the jsFiddle, therefore we can't see the side-effect you're having trouble with immediately. Find random images on google images and use the entire URL, instead of the current relative path.

Comment: Your code is really messy. like the above comment - try to post only the relevant parts - another thing you have an error in the events code - you can't put load event inside domready event - even if it works - it does not make any sense - what I can offer you without understanding your code is to use resize event of the window - and on resize just reposition the elements you want.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code in both the above question and the JS fiddle (particularly to the images) so I hope this helps for a solution. Jen

Comment: i would say it's a CSS issue, how about `#banner-container img { max-width:100%; height:auto;}` and `#banner-container {width : 50%; height:340px }`, 50% being the size you want (you have to get rid of the width and height attributes on your img tags…)

Comment: here is a jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/TE75y/11/

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code and tested it from Dreamweaver into Google Chrome and the solution worked but when I tried it in IE and Firefox, the whole site got messed up as in IE, the countdown clock moves to the left and in Firefox the images and the countdown clock move up covering the header and the navigation links. Is there a reason for this as I have been pondering for the last hour for a solution and I cannot come up with one. Also how can I make the make the images all the same size as it looks a little messy with one image size showing and then the next.

Comment: Also in IE, some of the images outstrech the site making the horizontal scroll bar going for ever just to see the image and the content moves to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just organised your code a bit and it's working now.

You should learn how to use jsfiddle (it is very simple) so look at my jsfiddle and learn.

http://jsfiddle.net/87ZkC/

put in html:

```
<div id="banner-container">

<div class="slides-wrapper">

<img src="http://routenote.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/festival-crowd.jpg" width="1090" height="340" alt="banner 5"/> 

<img src="http://unfoldstudentlife.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Glastonbury-2005-music-festival-Pyramid-Stage-CL.jpg" width="1090" height="340" alt="banner 7"/> 
<img src="http://www.cable-london.com/images/uploads/content/Festival_Crowd1.jpeg" width="1090" height="340" alt="creamfields"/> 

<img src="http://huntingothers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/festypic.jpg" width="1090" height="340" alt="creamfield 2"/> 
</div> 

</div>
```

put in css:

```
#banner-container {
position: relative;
height: 340px;
width: 960px;
margin-left: 450px;
}
#banner-container > div {
position: absolute;
top: 55px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
}

#banner-container img {
display: block;
position: absolute;
background-color: #F5F5F5;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
box-shadow: 0 0 22px #000000;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
height: 340px;
width: 960px;
}
```

put in js:

```
/* settings */
    var showDuration = 3000;
    var container = $('banner-container');
    var images = container.getElements('img');
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var interval;
    /* opacity and fade */
    images.each(function(img,i){ 
        if(i > 0) {
            img.set('opacity',0);
        }
    });
    /* worker */
    var show = function() {
        images[currentIndex].fade('out');
        images[currentIndex = currentIndex < images.length - 1 ? currentIndex+1 : 0].fade('in');
    };

var  interval = show.periodical(showDuration);
```

In addition include mootools in the left "Frameworks & Extensions" Section.

Comment: Hi Adidi, thanks for your help, I just want to know how can I position the slideshow so that it scales to the size of the browser window when resizing it and how can I do it so that it fits into all different browsers. Its just that I am now having problems as stated in the above comments that all the content has moved all over the place. I just do not know the solution for this.

Comment: somethins like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/87ZkC/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/87ZkC/1/) ?

Comment: Hi Adidi, I have modified the code, but for some reason, the slideshow is not working and it has filled out to the whole screen covering other content that is on the page, any ideas on why this has happened?

Comment: Yes - because I set in the position function the elements to be width,height of window - this is what you wanted no ? your words: "how can I position the slideshow so that it scales to the size of the browser window when resizing it"

Comment: Hi Adidi, I wanted it to scale so that when you minimize it goes to the window size, my apologies I did not write my question down properly. I wanted it to fit into the page with the other content as there are paragraphs of information underneath the slideshow and there is clock next to the banner.

Comment: Just uses the onresize window event to scale what you want when the window resize

Comment: Ok, but the slideshow is not working as I just tested it in the window broswer ( I have used the same code as you).

Comment: can you send me your original link so I can see what are you talking about - you are really not make yourself clear.

Comment: Hi Adidi, sorry for getting back late, I am working from a local host which demonstrates the slideshow problem clearer. The link I have posted here: http://festivalworld.net78.net/home.html attempts to show the same problem.

Comment: You have a js error there cause you code is in the head and not inside load/domready events or after the body. second - the 'slides-wrapper' element does not have any style - again - look at my example: [http://jsfiddle.net/87ZkC/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/87ZkC/1/)